# Laravel Multi Auth - Logical issue querying relationships for items owned by user_id

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, relationships

I have setup multi auth on my Laravel project. It's all working fine but I'm getting some crossed lines with the code I've already written.

I have tasks(todo's) which users own many of, so that I can use the following code.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return view('task.index', [
        'tasks' => $this->tasks->forUser($request->user()),
    ]);
}
```

**My problem is that my different user types have the same ID's so when user_type_a with the id of 1 logs in they see the tasks of user_type_b with the same id.**

I was going to just prefix the different user types with something e.g. user_type_a has the id of a_1 and user_type_b has the id of b_1. This doesn't seem like good practice though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure how this problem occurs... What type of ID are we talking about? Could you show some structure for the task model and user model?

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple multi-user system. All users in the same user table. The table has additional fields: is_admin, is_manager . If your have match more user roles - you can add additional table user_types. Then you can add scopes in model users like isAdmin(), isManger(), or etc. I did not have any problems belong developing this project. Everything is transparent and simple.